# Google Maps loading is very slow

Tags: performance, google-maps, dictionary

My site's Google map is very slow! When ever you do anything, zoom in or out or move the map, my loader spins for too long. I was told it is probably because everything is programmed to load before it will display. Any ideas?

Heres mine
[My Map](http://vacationrentalsbyrealtor.com/map-search/)

Heres one i would love to replicate, it is very fast. Follow link below and click "Map" in top right emnu bar next to "List".

[VRBO Map](http://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/new-jersey/shore/long-beach-island)

Comment: Your's loaded faster than theirs...

Comment: I don't mean the actual start up load time I meant when ever you zoom in or out or move anything, theirs moves in real-time and mine has the Loading thing that loads for long time.

Comment: I was bale to figure it out with the help of a friend. We commented out all references to the loader in the PHP. And we had to completely remove a DIV tag that had a "loader" class associated with it. And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

May be your api version are old, please make sure and then use latest loading supported version....

Use this version

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.5

instead of this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCONGB2LuIR6U3cT63dnC5IOzRWKWAGWAI&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places
(any...)